# How to set the width of \cancel

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, cancel

I have 2 TikZ nodes with fixed text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width = 3cm] (1){text text text text text text text text text text text text};
\node[text width = 3cm, below = of 1.south]{\cancel{text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as I understand `\cancel` text is inside `\hbox`, and LaTeX doesn't understand, how to split it into words.

Is it possible to set it's width as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use TikZ to draw the line instead, by giving the node a name and using the anchors `<nodename>.south west` and `<nodename>.north east`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width = 3cm] (1){text text text text text text text text text text text text};
\node (canceled) [text width = 3cm, below = of 1.south]{text text text text text text text text text text text text};
\draw (canceled.south west) -- (canceled.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
\node[text width = 3cm, below = of 1.south]{\cancel{%
    \begin{minipage}{3cm}
    text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \end{minipage}%
}};
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Note that the cancelled text is slightly moved to the right because of the offset of the line. Depending on your need for alignment, look at @Torbjørn T.'s answer.

Comment: Actually, the indentation is just a space caused by the linebreak after `\cancel{`. Add a percentage sign to remove it, i.e. `\cancel{%`. See the questions regarding end-of-line % listed in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2429/586

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Damn, you're right `>.<` - edited the code. The right end of the line is still a bit long, but that is caused by the linebreak in the `minipage` – is there any way to remove the extra whitespace at the right of the `minipage`?

Comment: One way would be to add `\usepackage{varwidth}` to the preamble and replace `minipage` with `varwidth`.